# Rails: possible to use fallback for duplicate polymorphic associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

Is there a way to define a polymorphic association that pulls from another poly assoc, but also then reverts to a backup poly assoc if the first one is empty? Maybe like this?

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :trip_itinerary_entries, :through => :trips, :source => :itinerary_entries
    has_many :template_itinerary_entries, :through => :templates, :source => :itinerary_entries
    has_many :entries, :from => :trip_itinerary_entries, :backup => :template_itinerary_entries
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would set up the two polymorphic associations (in my model and the required columns in my DB) and then create a method for getting both of the items (you don't want to override them method otherwise you would't be able to write new relationships).

```
def get_entries
  if entries.any?
    entries
  else
    template_itinerary_entries
  end
end
```

This way you can still use `entries` when you need to add items.

```
reserve = Reservation.new
reserve.entries << Entry.create()
```

But you could use the `get_entries` method to get either of the items.

```
reserve.get_entries
=> [template_itinerary_entries] # if there are no entries.
```